# T-SQL Group by with a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, where-clause

```
 Masterid    CC  CLA DES NLCLA   NLDES
 -------------------------------------
 53006141    CN  0   0   1       1
 53006141    US  1   1   1       1
 53006141    UK  1   1   0       0
 53006142    US  1   1   0       0
 53006142    UK  1   1   0       0
 53006143    CN  0   0   1       1
 53006143    US  1   1   0       0
 53006143    UK  1   1   0       0
```

From the above data I need to produce

- a list of `MasterIds` where there is `CC = US` or `CC = CN` and `NLCLA = 1` and `NLDES = 1`

The output should be

```
53006141
53006143
```

There has to be both CN and US under a MasterID.

Can someone help me to do this in SQL please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by adding a `WHERE` clause which will return rows with either `US` or `CN`:

```
select distinct Masterid
from yourtable
where cc in ('US', 'CN')
  and NLCLA = 1
  AND NLDES = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4758e/4)

If you want the result to include both the `CN` and `US`, then you can use:

```
select Masterid
from yourtable
where cc in ('US', 'CN')
  and NLCLA = 1
  AND NLDES = 1
group by masterid
having count(distinct cc) = 2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/968a1/2).

Another way that this could be done is using an `EXISTS` to get the list of MasterIds with both the `US` and `CN`. You then place the other filters in the `WHERE` clause and not in the subquery.

```
select distinct masterid
from yourtable t1
where exists (select Masterid
              from yourtable t2
              where cc in ('US', 'CN')
                and t1.masterid = t2.masterid
              group by masterid
              having count(distinct cc) = 2)
  and NLCLA = 1
  and NLDES = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/968a1/9)

Comment: what about if there is another row  <br />
53006144    CN  0   0   0       0

Comment: @LeBlues what do you mean if there is another row? What would you except the result to be in that case? It will return the same result -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/968a1/1

Comment: @LeBlues If that row exists, then it meets the criteria of the `WHERE`, so it will also return that row

Comment: @LeBlues see my edit, which will return only those records with both `US` and `CN`

Comment: it doesn't return 53006143

Comment: let me reface the question, i need to fine the masterids which has a CN  and a  US where there is NLDES = 1 and NLCLA = 1

Comment: @LeBlues you are welcome, you had me scratching my head for a minute

Answer (score 1):

One way is using a `CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Masterid,CC,CLA,DES,NLCLA,NLDES,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Masterid ORDER BY Masterid)
    FROM dbo.Table
    WHERE   CC IN('US', 'CN')
    AND     NLCLA = 1
    AND     NLDES = 1
)
SELECT Masterid FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4758e/8/0) ( thanks to bluefeet for fiddle-data )

Note that the `ROW_NUMBER` partition function would be helpful if you want to get a specific row, for example always the latest record for each `Masterid`. But since you haven't provided a `datetime` column i've just ordered arbitrarily by `Masterid`.