# Flatten count with one to many relationship

Tags: sql

I have two tables, `Person` and `Hobby`, with a one to many relationship.

```
| ID | Person |     | ID | PersonID | Hobby      |   
|----|--------|     |----|----------|------------|
| 1  | Bob    |     | 1  | 1        | Skiing     |
| 2  | Mike   |     | 2  | 2        | Biking     |  
| 3  | Frank  |     | 3  | 3        | Skiing     |
                    | 4  | 1        | Numerology |
                    | 5  | 2        | Witchcraft |
                    | 6  | 3        | Stamps     |
```

I want to produce a table that includes a single count for every person who likes Skiing or Stamps.
Something like this:

```
| Person | Count |
|--------|-------|
| Bob    | 1     |
| Frank  | 1     |
```

What would a working sql query look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL Group by with a where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835577/t-sql-group-by-with-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it.  You need to count distinct

```
SELECT p.person, count(Distinct p.id) as Count
FROM person p join hobby h
   ON h.personID = p.ID
WHERE h.hobby = 'Skiing' 
   OR h.hobby = 'Stamps'
GROUP BY p.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.person, count(p.id) as cnt
from person p join hobby h
on h.personid = p.id
where h.hobby = 'Skiing'
group by p.person
```

You have to join the tables and `group by` the person id.

Comment: What if it could equal Skiiing or biking, but I still only want to count it once?

Comment: you can use a `in` clause saying `hobby in ('Skiing','Biking')`

Comment: That gives me duplicate counts.  I only want to count once if they like any of the hobbies in the filtered in the Where clause.